# How to show AlertDialog when application is relaunched which previously exited using home button

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am new to Android I am developing an application in API level 2.2.
In my application whenever I press Home button it forces my app to exit. When I relaunch that app by clicking on its icon, it starts from where it exited.
I used *CountDownTimer* in my application and what i want is showing an Alert Dialog when relaunched.

```
protected void onResume()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Resume Current Excersize ?"); 
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
    {
      startCounterTime();//my method
      ....
     }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: add code of homebutton also

Comment: @Ameer: Home button(home screen button) of mobile not my apps

Comment: "whenever I press Home button it forces my app to exit" You are not talking about an application crash, right?

Comment: yes .it not crash it pause as it is but i want show Alert Dialog when it relaunched